# How to find the supremum and infimum of this set

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I'd like to be able to find $\inf A$ and $\sup A$ for the set $A = \{\cos{(\frac{\pi}{2}\lceil\root\of{n}\rceil)} - \cos{(\frac{\pi}{2}\root\of{n})} : n \in N_+\}$

I think that I know intuitively that the infimum and supremum will be $-1$ and $1$ respectively as it is clear to me from the ceiling function that the maximum - but unobtainable - difference in multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for the elements of $A$ is $1$, and investigating the graph of cosine would suggest that if we pick any two points on it no more than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ apart, we cannot exceed the infimum or supremum I have said.

Does anyone know how to prove this formally, and preferably in not too complex a way? Thank you!

Comment: We have $3\pi/4-\pi/4=\pi/2$ and $\cos(\pi/4)-\cos(3\pi/4)=\sqrt{2}$, so your intuitive supremum should be $\sqrt{2}$, not 1. Same for the infimum.

Comment: @HeathWinning But $\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil$ is always an integer, so $\cos \bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil\bigr)$ attains only the three values $-1,0,1$. Since $\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{n}$ trails by less than a quarter period, the difference is always $< 1$ in absolute value.

Comment: My apologies, my previous comment is not relevant